# Download MySQL table > than 2Gb in size

Tags: mysql, download, cpanel

I am using CPanel to host a website which works with MySQL table. Some of the table have rows which are created every second. Presently one of such table is of size 2Gb. I want download it and keep it as archive. While exporting it with phpmyadmin or database wizard of CPanel I am unable get SQL file more than 300Mb. Is there any way? Please help.

Comment: You should not do this via phpmyadmin or cpanel. Use mysqldump on the server (or via remote connection) to dump the data.

Comment: Thanks. I will try with mysqldump and let u know the result.

Comment: Thanks. I am new this MySQL thing and trying to gather experience from experts.

Comment: Export your table to the file which is local for MySQL server (use any built-in command line tool such as mysqldump or mysqlpump, or SELECT INTO OUTFILE). Then archive it and download.

Comment: Thanks Alina. I am off for today, will try with all prescribed solution and share my outcomes with all of you.